# Unpacking and packing back a struct consisting of single bytes

Tags: python, struct, pack

I am getting `struct.error: bad char in struct format` when packing bytes back in the struct even without making any changes to them.

I am trying to do bitwise operations on each byte in RGBTRIPLE of a 24-bit BMP image. For the sake of simplicity, I am posting the code with just one sample bytes sequence representing a pixel in a Bitmap; I don't make any bitwise operations on it, just try to pack it back.

```
from struct import *
from collections import namedtuple

def main():
    RGBTRIPLE = namedtuple('RGBTRIPLE', 'rgbtRed rgbtGreen rgbtBlue')
    rgbt_fmt = '=BBB'
    rgbt_size = calcsize(rgbt_fmt)

    rgbt_buffer = b'\x1c\x1e\x1f' 

    rgbt = RGBTRIPLE._make(unpack(rgbt_fmt, rgbt_buffer))

    rgbtRed = rgbt.rgbtRed
    rgbtGreen = rgbt.rgbtGreen
    rgbtBlue = rgbt.rgbtBlue

    rgbt_buffer = pack('rgbt_fmt', rgbtRed, rgbtGreen, rgbtBlue)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

From what I understand, the problem is that when I am unpacking bytes, I am getting ints with size > 1 byte. What is the best way to fix the size of those ints at 1 byte, so I can pack them back using the same `=BBB` struct format?

Comment: `pack('rgbt_fmt',` should be `pack(rgbt_fmt,`! i.e. `rgbt_fmt` is a variable name  not a string.

Comment: @PaulRooney Ooh. I wonder how did I miss it. Thank you!

Comment: No probs, easily done.